# Swagger UI examples using drf-spectacular and x-www-form-urlencoded requests

Tags: django, swagger, drf-spectacular

Is it possible to generate a swagger UI page (and redoc for that matter) that has examples for both application/json *and* x-www-form-urlencoded request bodies? I can get examples for application/json, but not when selecting x-www-form-urlencoded as the request type fro the swagger/redoc UIs.

I'm using the following decorator for the "create" method (in a ModelViewSet)

```
@extend_schema(request=MySerializer)
```

where MySerializer looks like the following...

```
@extend_schema_serializer(
    examples=[
        OpenApiExample(
            'Example input',
            description='Creation of an alias',
            value={
                'user_id': 1234567890,
                'obj_id': 288,
                'alias': 'my alias'
            },
            request_only=True,
            response_only=False,
        ),
    ],
)
class MySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    user_id = serializers.IntegerField()
    obj_id = serializers.IntegerField()
    alias = serializers.CharField(max_length=50)
```

The swagger/redocs UIs will happily provide an example dropbox with "Example Input" for an application/json request body (whereby selecting the example will populate the json), but for x-www-form-urlencoded will just  show a form to fill in, with no example dropbox in order to populate the fields.

I can get examples (and their selection drop boxes) for query strings, i.e. when making GET endpoints that use OpenApiParameter e.g.

```
@extend_schema(
        parameters=[
            OpenApiParameter(name='q', description='Query string to search for', required=True, type=str,
                examples=[
                    OpenApiExample(
                        'Search query',
                        value='foobar'
                    ),
                ]
            ),
            ...
        ]
    )
```

where selecting a drop box entry will populate the text field.

However, for x-www-form-urlencoded, this doesn't seem to get generated?

Is this possible? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to example data, Redoc is very manual in that there is very little automatic generation of examples based on the schema.

AFAIK SwaggerUI does generate a basic example from the schema, however also only for JSON.

If you want to have `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` examples, you likely need to specify each one manually. Not sure if the juice is worth the squeeze there.

Now to drf-spectacular: `OpenApiExample` are by default JSON, so if you want a different encoding you need to explicitly set it and also provide a properly encoded value string:

```py
        OpenApiExample(
            'Form-encoded example 1',
            value='YOUR HANDMADE FROM ENCODED DATA STRING',
            media_type='application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        )
```